# Text is busting out of the contained box

Tags: asp.net, html, css, user-controls

I have a user control that displays summary information, and it busts out of the contained box if the text is like:

```
<NOBR>00000000000000000000<wbr/>00000000000000000000...</NOBR>
```

I added the nobr and wbr tags, but it still doesn't force the text to wrap to the next line.

The entire row is displayed (with the "..."), so for sure it is not wrapping to the next line as "expected".

Comment: Why can't you just use <br>?  Can you paste any relevant CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here at the compatibility of the `wbr` tag in various browsers:  http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html.

Basically, it works in most browsers, but not IE8.  What browser are you testing this with?

Also, it appears that because you're using the `nobr` tag (which tells the browser not to break that line up no matter what), it won't matter what appears between those tags, but I haven't confirmed that.